# I am unable to send id to logout page

Tags: asp.net, .net

logout page:

```
public ActionResult Logout(string id) {
  var check1 = Convert.ToInt32(id);
  //var check = Convert.ToInt16(model.Id);        
  var logout= db.UserContext.Where(a=>a.Id == check1).FirstOrDefault();

  logout.Out_Time = DateTime.Now;
  db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;          
  //db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

dashboard index page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Login","",new { id = Session["Id"] })
```

After checking password and username id is not passed to the logout action method. Please give me any suggestion.

Logout page and dashboard controller is different. I want to change the out time. When the user logs out it shows the time in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `@Html.ActionLink(...)` method can take 4 string and routeParmas as arguments?

According to docs [@Html.ActionLink docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__) there is no such overload.

You can try to drop 4th string to meet this overload:

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString ActionLink (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
```

Comment: what is the object route value?

Comment: that is your last parameter - `new { id = Session["Id"] }`

P.S. set last param (htmlAttributes) as null
`@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Login",new { id = Session["Id"] }, null)`

Comment: Can you help me which linq query i use so that i display the employee time details which is the  first login time and last logout time  of each employee